# Actualizar tablas dinamicamente en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

Hola a todos antes que nada gracias por leer mi pregunta, lo que quiero realizar es algo raro y también puede conllevar a malas practicas sin embargo debo encontrar la manera de resolver esto, los pongo en contexto necesito actualizar tablas en mi base de datos dinamicamente, estas tablas o la tabla que debo actualizar es seleccionada por el usuario que controla el sistema por lo tanto la función encargada de esta tarea en mi controlador debe estar preparado para ello, he logrado lo siguiente; pondré datos estáticos más sin embargo estos datos llegan dinamicamente dependiendo de la tabla seleccionada.

Obtengo los datos que el usuario actualizo en el $request. Se verá de esta forma:

```
$request = [1,"darinel cigarroa","24","2021-12-16 00:00:00","2021-12-16 00:00:00"];
```

Obtengo la tabla que el usuario esta editando:

```
$table = "user";
```

La variable colums obtenida de getColumnListing se veria de esta forma:

```
$colums = ["id","nombre","edad","created_at","updated_at"];
```

Estos dos valores llegan a función de la manera que explico arriba. Mi función es la siguiente:

```
   public function update(Request $request, $table)
    {
        
        try {
        
            /* Esta es la consulta en SQL nativo esto es lo que debo lograr
            UPDATE public.vacunados
            SET id=1, nombre='darinel cigarroa', edad='24', created_at='16/12/21', updated_at='16/12/21'
            WHERE id = 1;
            */
            $colums = Schema::getColumnListing($table); // Obtengo las columnas de la tabla a actualizar
            $rows = $request; // Lo campos actualizados
            $consulta = null; // Aquí se me ocurre guardar mi consulta
            // Se me estaba ocurriendo hacer un doble ciclo for para ir generando mis campos de la siguiente manera
            foreach ($colums as $campo)
            {
                foreach($request as $rows){
                    $consulta = $campo . '=' . $rows;
                }
            }
            // Más si embargo esto me genera solo un string de esta forma: $consutla = "updated_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00";
        
            DB::statement("UPDATE $table SET $consulta where id = 1"); // Una idea de como quiero generar la consulta
 
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
            ], 200);

        } catch (\Exception | \Error $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'No se pudo completar la acción',
            ], 500);
        }
    }
```

He dejado toda la explicación y como va mi lógica hasta ahora para poder llevar acabo mi problema, les estaría muy agradecido a cualquier respuesta, idea, documentación de algo similar, para poder concluir de ante mano muchas gracias, si me he dejado explicar algo o necesitan más información háganme saber he iré actualizando la pregunta y subiendo lo que voy avanzando claro, de nuevo gracias.

Comment: Debería ser `$consulta += $campo . '=' . $rows;` (con el +) y tendrías que insertas las , correspondientes.

Comment: comprendo lo que quiere logra, pero la funcionalidad viola todos los patrones de MVC y los patrones de arquitectura de software, cuando tenga la necesidad de procesa datos en controlador se le va a dificulta los proceso

Comment: Gracias por usus comentarios, entiendo lo malo que es aplicar esta funcionalidad la parte buena es que solo funciona para un grupo limitados de tablas, aun sigo investigando de que manera resolver mi problema.